# Algorithm to distribute numbers so that average of sets is closest to total average

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Given a collection of N non-unique decimal numbers d<sub>1</sub>, d<sub>2</sub>, d<sub>3</sub> ... d<sub>N</sub> whose average is μ<sub>T</sub>.

Assume we distribute d<sub>1</sub>, d<sub>2</sub>, d<sub>3</sub> ... d<sub>N</sub> across K sets with sizes s<sub>1</sub>, s<sub>2</sub> ... s<sub>K</sub> and therefore:

$$\sum_{i=1}^K s_{i} = N$$

What is an efficient algorithm to distribute the numbers so that the following sum is minimal?

$$\sum_{i=1}^N \mid μ_{i} - μ_{T} \mid $$

Where μ<sub>i</sub> is the average of all numbers in set i.

Comment: You could also probably employ some quadratic programming

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot, because part of the the problem is deciding which set to put each value in.

Comment: Wait, are the set sizes fixed, or variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If set sizes $s_i$ are fixed, this problem can be cast as a binary linear program:
\begin{array}{llll}
\text{minimize}_{B,e} & \sum_i e_i \\
\text{subject to} & -s_i e_i \leq \sum_j B_{ij} (d_j - \mu_T) \leq s_i e_i & i=1,2,\dots, K \\
 & \sum_i B_{ij} = 1 && j=1,2,\dots, N \\
                  & \sum_j B_{ij} = s_i & i= 1,2,\dots, K \\
                  & B_{ij} \in \{0,1\} & i=1,2,\dots, K, & j=1,2,\dots, N
\end{array}
I make no claims that this is efficient---so feel free not to accept it as an answer. But the fact that it is so readily cast in this form suggests to me that the problem may be NP-hard.

My prior answer incorrectly identified your problem as a 1-D instance of $k$-means clustering; thank you to @Batman for pointing that out. I do wonder if a dynamic programming technique could be used in this case similar to the one offered for $k$-means. But fixing the number of values in each set may prevent such an approach from working.